# Derived Orderings in scala?

Tags: scala

I've occasionally found myself wanting a very simple Ordering[A] for a class which does not have an ordering yet. Usually the projection of a tuple or a field of a class. The following class seems to do this generically

```
case object Ord { 
  case class DerivedOrdering[A,B](fn : B=>A)(implicit o : Ordering[A]) extends Ordering[B] { 
      def compare(a:B, b:B) = o.compare(fn(a), fn(b)) 
  }
}
```

I haven't seen it in the scala library. Is it there somewhere?

Usage

```
Ord.DerivedOrdering[Int, (Int, List[Int])]( _._1)
```

Gives an ordering on (Int, List[Int]) ordering by the integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is something you can do which is a method in the standard library

```
def by[T, S](f: T => S)(implicit ord: Ordering[S]): Ordering[T]
```

for example you can do the following:

```
implicit val tupleOrdering = Ordering.by[(Int, List[Int]), Int] {
  _._1
}
```

Reuben

Comment: Pretty.  I had no idea that existed.

Answer (score 0):

Not per se, but you can do so at the call site.  Instead of saying

```
foo.sorted()
```

with the ordering you describe, you can say

```
foo.sortBy(_._1)
```

with whatever projection or even more complicated expression you wish, e.g

```
foo.sortBy(_._1.toLowercase)
```